# How to list the folder path of all VOBs

Tags: clearcase

I am writing a script to backup all the VOBs, which will need to get the list of VOB folders (All the `.vbs` folders) and feed them to the for loop in script, I was able to list the VOBs with command:

```
cleartool lsvob -short -host HOSTNAME
```

But how to list the VOB folder?

Answer (score 2):

A simple:

```
 cleartool lsvob -host HOSTNAME
```

is enough to display:

- the vob tag
- the vob storage path (or "[storage location](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21147041)")

(This is more convenient than a [`cleartool describe` on each vob](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_tshoot_mvfs_containers_vob.htm)).

This [script example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4687.html) contains:

```
system("cleartool lsVOB -host ${COMPUTERNAME} > $TMP_VOBINFO 2> $JUNK"); 
open(VOBS,$TMP_VOBINFO); 
while ($VOB=<VOBS>) { 
($active, $VOBtag, $VOBstrg) = split(/\s+/,$VOB);
```

(that extract the storage location for each vobs)

Comment: +1 for using the words 'clearcase' and 'simple' in the same post.

Comment: @RitchMelton: I admit, that is a bit daring ;) In my current mission, I do some RTC (Rational Team Concert), so ClearCase seems simple in comparison ;)

Comment: Wow. I'm impressed by your pain threshold. Are you a red-head?

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a Windows script example?